# Generate and Insert surrogate keys into already existing BigQuery table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-insert, create-table

I have an existing table without any unique ID. I'm planning to generate surrogate keys using `GENERATE_UUID()` statement however I'm sure not how to insert this new column... What is the best option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ... AS SELECT

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_a
AS SELECT GENERATE_UUID() uuid, * FROM table_a
```

The drawback is:

- The metadata of the table is lost (table options, column descriptions etc.)
- Nullability of the columns is lost, all columns becomes NULLABLE

If both are acceptable, then approach above is the simplest way

If not, then you need to add a column through [UI or API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#manually_adding_an_empty_column), then do

```sql
UPDATE table_a
SET uuid = GENERATE_UUID()
WHERE uuid IS NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way to combine the API call and the Update query?

Comment: Yes, there is. But for some reason, I cannot post it here. If you can create a ticket on BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers and paste the link back here. I can follow up with you on that ticket.